# DAX sameperiod remain empty for my Sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this formula to calculate Sales:

```
Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(fact[SaleValue]))
```

Then I write this to calculate Sales on the same period

```
SamePeriodLY = CALCULATE(SUM(fact[SaleValue]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(fact[SaleDate]))
```

when making a bar chart the value over the same period remain empty. What is the problem?[image]

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SamePeriodLY = CALCULATE(SUM(fact[SaleValue]),DATEADD(fact[SaleDate],-1,YEAR))
```

or

```
SamePeriodLY = CALCULATE(SUM(fact[SaleValue]),DATEADD(DATEVALUE(fact[SaleDate]),-1,YEAR))
```

Comment: it could be, DAX isn't recognizing fact[SaleDate] as Date Type. Try adding `DATEVALUE(fact[SaleDate])`.

Comment: not working with DATEVALUE, the column fact[SaleDate] is a date, so DATEVALUE return an error as fact[SaleDate] is not a text